# If I run a basicHttpBinding WCF endpoint in a windows service what windows features do I need to install?

Tags: .net, wcf

If I run a basicHttpBinding WCF endpoint in a windows service what Windows features do I need to install?

Do I need to install IIS? Do I need to install anything else?

I'm on Windows 2008 server x64 Standard

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're self hosting in a Windows Service, you shouldn't need any additional Windows features.  IIS would only be required if you were hosting in IIS.